# Playwright times out after any page.route usage

Tags: node.js, typescript, web-crawler, playwright

When I try to intercept any request using page, playwright just times out, even if nothing is changed:

```
import {chromium} from "playwright";

const b = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false
})

const p = await b.newPage();
await p.route('**/*', async (route) => {
    await route.continue();
});
await p.goto('https://www.google.com');
```

I would expect this code to just open google, but the loading spinner spins for a while, then timeout happens. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually a bug introduced in latest Chrome version:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/10376

I've managed to get my test setup working by disabling `acceptCHFrame` in `node_modules/playwright`.

Answer (score 0):

From [the examples here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-route), it looks like the route.continue() should not be awaited (and the handler is not an async function). Maybe that difference explains the timeout?